# How to await and return this array of products from JSON file

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to return an array of products like this.

```js
import * as rp from "request-promise";

const getProducts = async () => {
    const products = []
    await rp.get({
        uri: 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json',
        json: true,
    }).then(async data => {
        data['products_and_categories'].new.forEach(async element => {
            await rp.get({
                uri: `https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/${element.id}.json`,
                json: true,
            }).then(product => {
                products.push(product)
            })
        })
    })
    console.log(products)
    return products
}

getProducts()
```

This does not return an array full of products and when I log it the array is empty however I know that it works and that it is just a async issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm proposing not to mix `async/await` with `promises`

`forEach` will not work with `async/await`,

I refactor your code, it should be something like this

```
import * as rp from "request-promise";

const getProducts = async () => {

    const data = await rp.get({
        uri: 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json',
        json: true,
    })
    const products = await Promise.all(data['products_and_categories'].new.map(async element => {
        return rp.get({
            uri: `https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/${element.id}.json`,
            json: true,
        })
    }));

    console.log(products)
    return products
}

getProducts()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some very basics of async javascript concepts. I can see you using async/await syntax. Basically async/await is a better syntax for Promises. It promises with a better/more readable syntax.  async/await was introduced to give a better way of coding and to escape from so-called 'callback hell'. Now what you are doing here is mixing both those syntaxes. Either use async/await or use .then/.catch syntax. I think the code written by Lukasz answer here is perfect for your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
        const data = await rp.get({
            uri: 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/mobile_stock.json',
            json: true,
        });
        const promiseArr = [];
        data.products_and_categories.new.forEach(element => {
            const res = rp.get({
                uri: `https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/${element.id}.json`,
                json: true,
            })
            promiseArr.push(res)
        });
        return Promise.all(promiseArr)
    } catch (err) {

    }
}

(async function () {
    console.log(await getProducts())
})();
```